# 1980's movie with a man floating through space in a bubble with a woman and an alien with an elephant head

Tags: story-identification, movie

I tried my best to find something about a small scene I remember from a movie I watched when I was little, in the 1980's, but could not find anything on my own. All I remember is the following scene.

A man (might be a teenager) is floating through space in a bubble. Along with him is a woman (or teenage girl) and some kind of humanoid alien with an elephant shaped head. From its trunk a small flame pops out that the man uses to light a cigarette.

Comment: Animated, or live action?  Was the bubble fully transparent or mostly opaque, with or without portholes or windows?

Comment: Possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70770/is-there-a-tv-show-movie-with-humanoid-aliens-evolved-from-elephants

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/PodPeople has an elephant-like character, and a bubble approaching Earth, but falls apart after that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Seems like a decent enough match to me.

Comment: It wasn't Pod People. Of that I am very sure. It was a more menacing large humanoid creature. The more I think about it I believe it was initially the villain. And it was live action not animated.

Comment: The movie you're looking for is [Visitors from the Arkana Galaxy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082466/) from 1981. It ends with the scene you mentioned (astronaut lighting his cigarette with the alien's trunk in space). However, it seems to be a duplicate of [Identify movie with monster (alien?) that has some kind of proboscis/trunk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32142/identify-movie-with-monster-alien-that-has-some-kind-of-proboscis-trunk), so I voted to close. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Walt Not a dupe, ___both___ questions need to have the same answer and have had the OP confirm that is what they were looking for.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I see. Thanks. I'll provide the answer, then.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [*Visitors from the Arkana Galaxy*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082466/) from 1981. It ends with the scene you described: With an astronaut (and a space woman and a couple of space kids) floating in space and the man lighting his cigarette with the alien's trunk. The final scene is in the film's poster (see [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitors_from_the_Galaxy)) and you can see that weird alien here on the left:

[image: The poster showing two characters each on a starry background; on the left is a pink alien creature with ribbed "skin" and a got-like head but massive eyes with two female characters with pink hair and gold skin tight suits; on the right a female with a gold skin tight suit; bald, large head and large ribbed ears]